# if $X\sim U(0,1)$ show that $(b-a)X+a \sim U(a,b)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm using the MGF method, this is what I get:
$$
\begin{align}
Y&=(b-a)X+a\\
M_Y(t)&=E[e^{(b-a)X}e^a] \\
&=E[e^{(b-a)X]}e^a &\text{I think this is my error} \\
&= M_x((b-a)t)e^a\\
&=E[\dfrac{e^{(b-a)t}}{(b-a)t}]e^a
\end{align}
$$

and then the $e^a$ messes it up.

Comment: Is it required to use MGF? You can simply use CDF.

Comment: I could. but I was wondering why this method didnt work for me.

Comment: The MGF of $Y$ is $\mathbb{E}[e^{tY}]$ so you should have $\mathbb{E}[e^{t(b-a)X+ta}]$ rather than what you've written.

Comment: then my last equation would have $e^at$ instead of $e^a$ right? which would still be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original definition of the MGF can't be right - it doesn't involve $t$.  I also think you (incorrectly) added an expectation to the MGF for $X$, after it had already been computed.

Instead:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}M_Y(t)=\E[e^{t((b-a)X+a)}]=e^{at}\E[e^{t(b-a)X}]=e^{at}M_X((b-a)t)
$$
Assuming you have already shown that the MGF of a uniform variable on $(0,1)$ is
$$
M_X(t)=\frac{e^t-1}{t},
$$
this yields
$$
M_Y(t)=e^{at}\frac{e^{(b-a)t}-1}{(b-a)t}=\frac{e^{bt}-e^{at}}{(b-a)t},
$$
as you wanted.

Comment: cant be write ;) haha. Thanks!

Comment: :-)  Ha ha, yeah, that was a "not enough coffee" moment for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y=(b-a)X+a$:
$$P(Y \leq y) = P(X \leq \frac{y-a}{b-a})$$
$$= \frac{y-a}{b-a}$$
$$P(Y = y) = \frac{d}{dy}P(Y \leq y) =\frac{1}{b-a}$$